# Connect to CloudSql from Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataflow

When Connecting to CloudSql from Google Dataflow job

```
public String cnstr = "jdbc:google:mysql://xxx:zzz:yyy/dbname?user=root&amp;password=****";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(cnstr);
                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(selectSql))
```

I got this error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:google:mysql://
```

Any Help?

Comment: Thanks. But your answer is for appengine while I am running the code in a dataflow job, so your solution will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change the connection string to

```
jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/dbname?user=root&password=****
```

And now it is working perfectly;

Comment: Very strange. I am also just trying it right now and keep getting the "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/__db_name__" error.

Comment: Which instance of cloud sql does this connect to? What if I have multiple cloud sql instances?